# Como eu faça para associar um carro a um motorista nesse código que eu fiz

Tags: c, arquivo, struct

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>
 
typedef struct Motorista{
    int driver_id; // id do motorista
    int idade; // idade do motorista
    int telefone; // telefone do motorista
    char nome[50]; // nome do motorista
}motorista; // estrutura do motorista
 
typedef struct Carro{
    int car_id; // id do carro
    char marca[50]; // marca do carro
    char modelo[50]; // modelo do carro
}carro; // estrutura do carro

 
 
void add_driver(){ // função para adicionarr motorista 

    motorista driver;
    FILE *m;
    m = fopen("motoristasss.txt","ab");   
    
    if(m == NULL){
        printf("       [!]problemas na abertura do arquivo...");
    }else{
        do{
            system("cls");
            printf("\n  #-------------  Cadastro motorista  -------------#");
            printf("\n  |                                                |");
            printf("\n  #------------------------------------------------#");
            
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("\n\n      >Insira o nome do  motorista: ");
            gets(driver.nome); 
            
            
            printf("\n\n      >Insira o id do motorista: ");
            scanf("%d",&driver.driver_id);
            fwrite(&driver, sizeof(motorista), 1, m);
            
            printf("\n\n      >Insira a idade do motorista: ");
            scanf("%d",&driver.idade);
            fwrite(&driver, sizeof(motorista), 1, m);
            
            printf("\n\n      >Insira o telefone do motorista: ");
            scanf("%d",&driver.telefone);
            fwrite(&driver, sizeof(motorista), 1, m);
            
            printf("\n\n      [!]Deseja adicionar mais um motorista? (s/n)? ");
            
        }while(getche() == 's');
        fclose(m);
    }
    
   
}

void listar_driver(){
    system("cls");
    motorista driver;
    FILE *m;
    m = fopen("motoristasss.txt","rb");   
    
    if(m == NULL){
        printf("       [!]problemas na abertura do arquivo...");
    }else{
        while(fread(&driver, sizeof(motorista), 1, m)==1){
            
            printf("\n#---------------------------------------------------#");
            printf("\n|    Nome do motorista: %s                          ",driver.nome);
            printf("\n|    Id do motorista: %d                            ",driver.driver_id);
            printf("\n|    Idade: %d                                      ",driver.idade);
            printf("\n|    Telefone: %d                                   ",driver.telefone);
            printf("\n#---------------------------------------------------#\n\n");
        }
    }
    fclose(m);
    getch();
}

void add_car(){ // função para adicionar carros
    carro car;
    FILE *c;
    c = fopen("carross.txt","ab");   
    
    if(c == NULL){
        printf("       [!]problemas na abertura do arquivo...");
    }else{
        do{
            system("cls");
            printf("\n  #-------------  Cadastro Carro  -----------------#");
            printf("\n  |                                                |");
            printf("\n  #------------------------------------------------#");
            
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("\n\n      >Insira o a marca do carro: ");
            gets(car.marca); 
            
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("\n\n      >Insira o modelo do carro: ");
            gets(car.modelo); 
            
            
            printf("\n\n      >Insira o id do carro: ");
            scanf("%d",&car.car_id);
            fwrite(&car, sizeof(carro), 1, c);
            
        
            
            printf("\n\n      [!]Deseja adicionar mais um motorista? (s/n)? ");
            
        }while(getche() == 's');
        fclose(c);
    }
    
}
 
void listar_car(){
    system("cls");
    carro car;
    FILE *c;
    c = fopen("carross.txt","rb");   
    
    if(c == NULL){
        printf("       [!]problemas na abertura do arquivo...");
    }else{
        while(fread(&car, sizeof(carro), 1, c)==1){
            
            printf("\n#---------------------------------------------------#");
            printf("\n|    Marca do Carro: %s                          ",car.marca);
            printf("\n|    Modelo do Carro: %s                            ",car.modelo);
            printf("\n|    ID do carro: %d                                      ",car.car_id);
            printf("\n#---------------------------------------------------#\n\n");
        }
    }
    fclose(c);
    getch();
}
 
void remove_driver(){ // função para remover motorisra
    system("cls");
    listar_driver();
    motorista driver;
    FILE *m, *temporario;
    m = fopen("motoristasss.txt","r+");   
    temporario = fopen("temp.txt","w");
    int id;
    printf("\n\n      >Insira o id do motorista que você deseja excluir : ");
    scanf("%d",&id);

    
    if(m == NULL){
        printf("       [!]problemas na abertura do arquivo...");
    }else{
        while(fread(&driver, sizeof(motorista), 1, m)==1){
            if(id != driver.driver_id){
                fwrite(&driver, sizeof(motorista), 1, temporario);
            }
            
            
        }
    }
    
    if(ferror(temporario)){
        printf("\n        [!]Erro ao excluir\n");
    }else{
        printf("\n-----------Excluído com sucesso!-------------");
    }
    
    fclose(temporario);
    fclose(m);
    remove("motoristasss.txt");
    rename("temp.txt", "motoristasss.txt");

    getch();
     
}
 
void remove_car(){ // função para remover carro

system("cls");
    listar_car();
    carro car;
    FILE *c, *temporario;
    c = fopen("caross.txt","r+");   
    temporario = fopen("temp.txt","w");
    
    int id;
    printf("\n\n      >Insira o id do carro que você deseja excluir : ");
    scanf("%d",&id);

    
    if(c == NULL){
        printf("       [!]problemas na abertura do arquivo...");
    }else{
        while(fread(&car, sizeof(carro), 1, c)==1){
            if(id != car.car_id){
                fwrite(&car, sizeof(carro), 1, temporario);
            }
            
            
        }
    }
    
    if(ferror(temporario)){
        printf("\n        [!]Erro ao excluir\n");
    }else{
        printf("\n-----------Excluído com sucesso!-------------");
    }
    
    fclose(temporario);
    fclose(c);
    remove("carross.txt");
    rename("temp.txt", "carross.txt");

    getch();
      
}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    int cadastrar;
    do{
        system("cls");
        printf("\n  #-------------  Cadastro carro e motorista  -------------#");
        printf("\n  |                                                        |");
        printf("\n  |                    Menu principal                      |");
        printf("\n  |                                                        |"); 
        printf("\n  |      1- Cadastrar motorista                            |");
        printf("\n  |      2- Cadastrar carro                                |");
        printf("\n  |      3- Remover carro                                  |");
        printf("\n  |      4- Remover motorista                              |");
        printf("\n  |      5- Listar Motoristas                              |");
        printf("\n  |      6- Listar Carros                                  |");
        printf("\n  |      7- Sair                                           |");
        printf("\n  #--------------------------------------------------------#\n");
        printf("\n          >Escolha uma opção: ");


    scanf("%d",&cadastrar);
    
    switch(cadastrar){
        case 1:
            add_driver();
            getch();
            break;
            
        case 2:
            add_car();
            getch();
            break;
            
        case 3:
            remove_car();
            getch();
            break;
            
        case 4:
            remove_driver();
            getch();
            break;
        
        case 5:
            listar_driver();
            getch();
            break;
        
        case 6:
            listar_car();
            getch();
            break;
    }
 }while(cadastrar <= 6 && cadastrar !=0); // laço 
 
  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não sei se entendi bem, mas você pode criar uma `struct` com um carro e um motorista

Comment: Use um banco de dados. [MySQL 8.0 C API Developer Guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/), [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html), [PostgreSQL C Library](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/libpq.html)

Comment: O problema me parece é que o autor da pergunta começou a escrever código antes de ter uma clara noção de como o sistema deveria funcionar. É um problema de modelagem de software e de dados. Então, adicionar um banco de dados, não só não vai resolver o problema como vai adicionar uma camada extra de complexidade. Quanto à pergunta em si, acho que o autor deveria esclarecer o que o programa dele deve fazer, quais são os requisitos e regras de negócio, e quais funcionalidades ele deseja acrescentar com essa relação carro x motorista.

Answer (score 1):

Veja esse conjunto por exemplo:

```
typedef struct 
{
    int  id;
    int  idade;   
    int  telefone;
    char nome[50]; 

}   Motorista;         


typedef struct 
{
    int  id;
    char marca[50];
    char modelo[50];

}   Carro;       


typedef struct
{
    int         id;
    Carro*      carro;
    Motorista*  motorista;

}   Em_servico; // associa carro e motorista


typedef struct
{
    int             id;
    unsigned        n_carros;
    Carro**         car;
    unsigned        n_motoristas;
    Motorista**     mot;
    unsigned        n_on_line;
    Em_servico**    on_line;  // motoristas e carros em servico

}   Frota;
```

Essa é uma construção típica de bancos de dados. `Em_servico` associa um carro ao motorista, como em uma frota de taxis na hora em que um motorista pega uma viatura e deixa o galpão.

`Frota` é um retrato da situação de momento, com todos os carros, motoristas e a lista dos que estão em serviço.

Comment: Como ele vai fazer para persistir esse relacionamento num arquivo texto e depois o recuperar?

Comment: seguindo no modo banco de dados :) grava um simples arquivo com toda a `Frota` ou apenas os pares `id` \ `id`  no encerramento e lê na abertura. E grava um arquivo **journal** com as transações para fazer o `replay` se cair o sistema antes do fechamento